# cannot create core in solrj with embeddedsolrserver

Tags: solrj

this is my code:

```
File home = new File(System.getProperty("solr.solr.home"));
        CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(home.getAbsolutePath());
        CoreAdminRequest.Create create = new CoreAdminRequest.Create();
        create.setCoreName("newCoreName");
        create.setCoreNodeName("newCoreName");
        create.setAction(CoreAdminAction.CREATE);
        create.setInstanceDir(home.getAbsolutePath()); 
        create.process(new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, ""));
```

When I run this, I get "no such core: "" " exception.
If I change it to:

```
create.process(new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "newCoreName"));
```

I get "no such core: "newCoreName" " exception.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

We have found there are two things required to create a core:
1) There has to be a default core
2) The directory to be used for the new core should be created.

The solr.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores defaultCoreName="empty" adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core instanceDir="empty/" name="empty"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

To create a new core do the following:

```
File home = new File(scfg.getIndexHome());
File solr = new File(home, "solr.xml");
String corename = "newcore";
CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(home, solr);
//create the directory
File f = new File(home, corename); f.mkdirs();
SolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "empty"); //default
//create the core
CoreAdminRequest.createCore(corename, corename, server, "solrconfig.xml", "schema.xml");
//persist it in the solr.xml
CoreAdminRequest.persist("solr.xml", server);
SolrServer servernew = new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, corename);
```